# perl regex for allchars in between (ex: start*end)

Tags: regex, perl

I need to filter strings like this:

```
abc-somerandomchars-1.xml
xyz-somerandomstuff-1.xml
```

I'd like to filter strings that have a known beginning string (ex: abc, xyz) and ending string (ex: xml), I don't care about the characters in between the start and end string

I tried something like /($start).*.($end)/ but does not seem to be working as expected.
please suggest.

Comment: show an explicit example that didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
((?:abc|xyz).*\.xml)
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wH0cH3)**

**Explanation:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked. And thank you again for sharing the regex site, its very handy (bookmarked right away!)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following expression:

```
/^(abc|xyz).*\.xml$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match at the start and end of the string, rather than somewhere in the middle, you need anchors: \A matches the start of the string, \z matches the end.  If your $start and $end may contain special characters but you want them to match literally, escape the special characters with \ (\Q...\E does this for you).  So:

```
/\A\Q$start\E.*\Q$end\E\z/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cat test 
xyz-somerandomchars-1.xml
abc-somerandomchars-1.xml

$ perl -p -e 's/^(abc|xyz)(.*)\.xml$/$2/g' test 
-somerandomchars-1
-somerandomchars-1
```

**UPDATE:** (After reading @Vijay's Comment)

```
$ cat test 
xyz-somerandomchars-1.xml
abc-somerandomchars-1.xml
qwerxyz-somerandomchars-1.xml
abc-somerandomchars-1.xml.dwdwd

$ perl -n -e 'print if /^(abc|xyz)(.*)\.xml$/' test 
xyz-somerandomchars-1.xml
abc-somerandomchars-1.xml
```

Comment: the OP just want to filter the strings but not replace the whole string.

Comment: @Vijay, Define what do you mean by `filter`.

Comment: He means there are lot of other strings in the file  and he wants to see only those strings which have that pattren .

Answer (score -1):

All the above answers are correct but won't generalize much. Here is a more intelligent approach

```
/^[a-z]+-.*\.xml$/
```

This will capture any fixed beginning alphabetic pattern. You can also include numbers if you want.

Comment: You can reach maximum intelligence and make this fully general by replacing it with `.*`